# What makes named pipes special as compared to regular files?

Tags: linux, fifo

Take this:

- in one terminal,

  ```bash
  touch myfile
  echo some text >> myfile
  # returns straight away
  ```
- in another terminal,

  ```bash
  cat myfile
  # prints "some text"
  ```
- now I can `rm myfile`

Now this:

- in one terminal

  ```bash
  mkfifo mypipe
  echo some text > mypipe
  # does not return yet
  ```
- in another terminal

  ```bash
  cat mypipe
  # prints "some text"
  ```
- the `echo` in the first terminal returns
- now I can `rm myfifo`

The only differences I see between the two scenarii are

1. one uses `touch` and one uses `mkfifo` to create a "file", which without knowing anything else, is just like using another command to do a similar thing,
2. most importantly, `echo`ing to the pipe doens't return until the read operation returns.

I guess 2 is what makes named pipes special as compared to regular files.

**But how are named pipes special?**

I read they are for inter process communication, but I would argue that processes could also just use regular files. But if that was the case, pipes wouldn't exist, so I must be wrong.

---

Here's one very simple example that totally confuses me:

If in one terminal I do

```bash
mkfifo mypipe
while true; do date > mypipe ; done
```

it will keep writing (overwriting, as I understand) to the pipe, but a single read from the pipe produces more output than I'd expect, e.g. this

```bash
cat myfifo
```

prints the same date more times, generally 4, but at times 5 or 6.

Comment: Sure, you could use regular files, but then the processes will need to coordinate clearing out processed data, or you'd be unnecessarily using up disk space.

Comment: Er, well, for one, consider what happens if you run `cat myfile` vs. `cat mypipe` _again_, with or without writing more into the file. Plus you already mentioned the thing about blocking on open. Asking how pipes _differ_ from regular files seems to imply the presumption that they're mostly _similar_, which I don't think is necessarily a good way of thinking about it. How would you consider e.g. the difference between a regular file and a character device that represented a serial (UART) connection?

Comment: See also e.g. https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man7/pipe.7.html if you haven't already, and maybe the links in the "pipe" tag wiki at https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/pipe/info